# How to alternate lower and upper case on dictionary keys? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, uppercase, lowercase

im new on python 3.

What I want to do is to alternate upper and lowercase but only on a dictionary key.

my dictionary is created from a list, its key is the word (or list element) and its value is the times this element appears in the list.

```
kb     = str(input("Give me a string: "));
txt    = kb.lower();      #Turn string into lowercase
cadena = txt.split();     #Turn string into list
dicc   = {};              

for word in cadena:
         if (word in dicc):
             dicc[word] = dicc[word] + 1
         else:
             dicc[word] = 1
print(dicc)
```

With this code i can get for example:

```
input: "Hi I like PYthon i am UsING python"
{'hi': 1, 'i': 2, 'like': 1, 'python': 2, 'am': 1, 'using': 1}
```

but what I am trying to get is actually is:

```
{'hi': 1, 'I': 2, 'like': 1, 'PYTHON': 2, 'am': 1, 'USING': 1}
```

I tried using this:

```
for n in dicc.keys():
    if (g%2 == 0):
        n.upper()

    else:
        n.lower()
print(dicc)
```

But it seems that I have no idea of what I'm doing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are confusing the key with its position in the array of keys

Comment: Also, note that dictionary order is nondeterministic before python 3.7. I personally wouldn't rely on dictionary order regardless; use `collections.OrderedDict` instead

Comment: Are you only trying to print your keys with the upper/lower case pattern, or do you actually want to modify the dict so that your keys are in alternating upper and lowercase order?

Comment: What do you want from the string "bad bad bad"?  Would you want the dict `{"bad": 3}` or `{"bad":2, "BAD":1}` ?

Comment: Also... you need to read up on how dictionaries work in Python. Where did you get the idea that `.item()` would work?

Comment: Actually I am trying to modify the dict, Carol.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools` and `collections.OrderedDict` (to guarantee order in Python < 3.7)

***Setup***

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

s = 'Hi I like PYthon i am UsING python'
switcher = itertools.cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
d = OrderedDict()
final = OrderedDict()
```

---

First, create an `OrderedDictionary` just to count the occurences of strings in your list (since you want matches to be case insensitive based on your output):

```
for word in s.lower().split():
    d.setdefault(word, 0)
    d[word] += 1
```

Next, use `itertools.cycle` to call `str.lower` or `str.upper` on keys and create your final dictionary:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    final[next(switcher)(k)] = v

print(final)
```

```
OrderedDict([('hi', 1), ('I', 2), ('like', 1), ('PYTHON', 2), ('am', 1), ('USING', 1)])
```

Comment: Can be generalized to cycle over `(op.methodcaller('lower'), op.methodcaller('upper'))`.

Comment: Hey, thank you! This is giving me an idea, actually I am trying to modify the dict but certainly this is helping me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `n in dicc.keys()` line is wrong. You are trying to use `n` as both the position in the array of keys and the key itself.

Also the semicolons are unnecessary.

This should do what you want:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Receive user input

kb     = str(input("Give me a string: "))
txt    = kb.lower()
cadena = txt.split()
dicc   = OrderedDict()

# Construct the word counter

for word in cadena:
    if word in dicc:
        dicc[word] += 1
    else:
        dicc[word] = 1
```

If you just want to *print* the output with alternating case, you can do something like this:

```
# Print the word counter with alternating case

elems = []
for i, (word, wordcount) in enumerate(dicc.items()):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        word = word.upper()
    elems.append('{}: {}'.format(word, wordcount)

print('{' + ', '.join(elems) + '}')
```

Or you can make a new OrderedDict with alternating case...

```
dicc_alt_case = OrderedDict((word.upper() if (i % 2 == 0) else word, wordcount)
                            for word, wordcount in dicc.items())
```